# Why the application goes to onPause state when we receive call and onStop state when we receive a message?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have created a Application and when a call is received my application goes to onPause() state but when I receive a message and open it , it goes to onStop() method. Can Anyone clarify why its different in this two situation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: In three seriousness the app may go to onPause() state:-
1. Some event interrupts app execution, as described in the onResume() section. This is the most common case.

2. In Android 7.0 (API level 24) or higher, multiple apps run in multi-window mode. Because only one of the apps (windows) has focus at any time, the system pauses all of the other apps.

3. A new, semi-transparent activity (such as a dialog) opens. As long as the activity is still partially visible but not in focus, it remains paused.

Comment: does that mean a when a phone call is received the dialer that is opened is a semi transparent activity.

Comment: That would depend upon device, as manufacturers tend to modify the in-call behavior.